# how do i divide a number by two multiple times

Tags: python

Can you help me help my son with python homework?
His homework this week is on iteration. We've worked through most of it, but we can't make much headway with the following:

"•  Write a program that will ask a user to enter a number between 1 and 100.  The program should keep dividing the number by 2 until it reaches a number less than 2.  The program should tell the user how many times it had to divide by 2. "

Can you help us with this, and preferably include some # lines in the code so we can better understand what's happening?

Comment: Hints: 1) Use [input](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_input.asp) to input number, 2)  [int](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/int) to convert to string to int, 3) [while loop]https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/while-loop), 4) [integer division](https://riptutorial.com/python/example/2797/integer-division) to divide by two.

Comment: @DarrylG You missed a bracket before your link :)

Comment: Stackoverflow is not for solving homework for people. At least  let us know how you attempted to solve the problem (simple working code example) please.

Comment: Best father of the world. @Neil keep in mind, try first all the possible trial then share your problem here with your trial code. It’s good for your son and stack overflow community

Answer (score 5):

Great that you're helping your son with his homework! Very exciting!

If I summarize the question, it is:

1. take a number n
2. divide it by 2
3. repeat step 2 until your number is less than 2
4. output how often it had to be divided

Let's do this by hand:

- I take a number, 15:
- I divide once, I get 7.5
- it's not less than 2, so I continue
- I divide by 2 again (2 times total), I get 3.75
- it's not less than 2, so I continue
- I divide by 2 again (3 times total), I get 1.875
- it's less than 2, so I stop

I had to divide by three times total.

If you were to take these steps and write it in code, how would you do this? (Hint: use a while loop!)

Comment: Well done. Not doing the stuff but still helping them.

Answer (score 1):

```py
num = int(input("Input number: "))    # 1
if num > 100 or num < 1:              # 2
    print("Error!")                   # 3
else:                                 # 4
    times = 0                         # 5
    while num >= 2:                   # 6
        num /= 2                      # 7
        times += 1                    # 8
    print(times)                      # 9
```

---

Program start.
Line 1: accept input, and convert to ``int``. Use 18 as example.
Line 2: check that number is 1~100. 18 is, so jump to line 4.
Line 4: enter ``else`` block.
Line 5: set a variable ``times`` to 0 to count times.
Line 6: enter ``while`` loop. In this case 18≥2, so enter.
Line 7: set ``num`` to ``num``÷2. In this case, num is set to *9*.
Line 8: increment ``times``. ``times`` is set to 1.
Line 6: 9≥2, so continue to line 7.
Line 7: set ``num`` to 9÷2=**4.5**.
Line 8: increment ``times`` again. ``times``=2.
Line 6: 4.5≥2, go on to line 7.
Line 7: set ``num`` to 4.5÷2=**2.25**.
Line 8: ``times`` is set to 3.
Line 6: 2.25≥2, go on.
Line 7: set ``num`` to 2.25÷2=**1.125**.
Line 8: ``times`` increased to 4.
Line 6: 1.125
Line 9: output the times needed, in this case 4.
Program finish.